# Can we make an image dynamic in WordPress that is set as background in Style.css?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, customization

I have converted **HTML template** to **WP theme**. and want to make everything dynamic.
Firstly I want to make my slider (Slider parts i.e. img, heading, content, button) dynamic.

Now all code is available in **index.php** except Image so I had made all other contents(heading, text, detailed content, buttons) dynamic in that file but Image is available in **Style.css**. Code is below:

```
#HeroBanner {
        background: url(../images/banner.jpg)no-repeat 0 0 / cover;
        height: 630px;
        position: relative;
    }
```

Now this ID(#HeroBanner) is called in **index.php** to display img on slider. Code is below:-

```
<section id="HeroBanner">
    <div id="BannerSlider" class="owl-carousel">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="banner-text">
                            <h1>Our work is dedicated to the<br /> prosperity of our clients! </h1>
                            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec tetuer
                            <br /> adipiscing elit. Praesent vestibu lum molestie
                            <br />lacus. Aenean nonummy hendrerit
                            <br />maurishasellus </p>
                                <div class="bannet-cta">
                                    <div class="cta-1">
                                        <a href="#">Click Here</a>
                                    </div>
                                <div class="cta-2">
                                    <a href="#">Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

please guide me Can I make this image dynamic? If yes, then how is it possible?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can use wordpress customizer api to customize your theme and add an option for the user in theme customization options.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more or provide me some detailed link?

Comment: Checkout the Wordpress Theme Customizer API at : https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're trying to make background images dynamic in your WordPress theme. You can do something like this:

In your functions.php file register a customizer and add an action hook to execute the customization.

```
function mytheme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {

}
 add_action( 'customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register' );
```

and if you follow the theme customization api in wordpress documentation at: https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API
You can see we have three things in our Customization.

1. Panels. 2. Sections. And 3rd Settings. We first have to create a Panel and inside that panel we can have a section or multiple sections and for each section we can have multiple settings and for each setting we've a controller that controls that setting. For example.

   ```
   $wp_customize->add_panel('panel_id',array(
        'panel'=>'panel_id',
        'title'=>__('Theme Options'),
        'priority'=>10,
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_section( 'Header' , array(
        'panel'=> 'panel_id',
        'title'      => __( 'Headers', 'mytheme' ),
        'priority'   => 30,
    ) );

    /*
        Background Image Custmoization
    */
    $wp_customize->add_setting('header_slider_image', array(
        'default'           => 'mydefault image link',
        'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
        'type'           => 'theme_mod',
        'transport' => 'refresh'

    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control($wp_customize, 'image_upload_test', array(
        'label'    => __('Header Image', 'gym'),
        'section'  => 'Header',
        'settings' => 'header_slider_image',
    )));
   ```

This can add the functionality to your theme customization option inside a Theme Options > Header > And Background Image. You can then call that image from customization sidebar by using the `get_theme_mod('setting_name');` wordpress function inside your page.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the customizer api and also check out this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) which allows you to add custom fields and assign them to any template. This way, you can have an image upload option on any page/template and then call it anywhere in your code. Also, it provides a theme options kind of functionality that could be used globally. You can research it [here.](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-page/)

Comment: I have added "Advanced Custom field" Plugin for this purpose and assigned it to my home page that allowed me to add other custom fields . I have done it already and made my other content of this page dynamic. Only problem is to get image from database because it is available in "style.css". Please re-read my question carefully and you will get my point. Thanks.

Comment: You can use `style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_field('whatever_value'); ?>);" ` on the div and assign a class to this element too. You can add extra styles like `background-size: cover` etc on that class in the css file then.